# Do Zabbix docker containers rely on dnsmasq in host?

Tags: docker, zabbix, dnsmasq

In Subspace docker installation instructions [they tell me](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-install-subspace-on-ubuntu-server) to remove the dnsmasq package "*because it will run inside the (Subspace) container*" .

On the same machine I want to run a Zabbix container. When the latter depends on the host dnsmasq I should not remove the package. So my question is will the Zabbix container also include a dnsmasq service? Does it need the host's? Or can you provide me hints how to find this out myself?

Comment: You need to figure out how you want to set up dhcp and dns. There's a reason it's hierarchical. Normally you don't need many of either resource.